# How to create changing colors using DataStore?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to create a color changing mechanism in my android app (using Jetpack compose material3 and DataStore) and have some problems with type mismatch. This app must change color on the other screen, using Dropdown menu. Help me to find and error an improve the code.

Here's my DataStoreManager class:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.longPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore
import com.example.drawercolorchange.ui.theme.MyGray
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map

private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("data_store")
class DataStoreManager(val context: Context) {

    suspend fun saveColor(color: Long){
        context.dataStore.edit{
            pref ->
            pref[longPreferencesKey("color")] = color
        }
    }

    fun getSettings() = context.dataStore.data.map{
        pref ->
        return@map pref[longPreferencesKey("color")] ?: MyGray
    }
}
```

It's screens(Main Screen and Settings screen with Dropdown menu):

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(){
    Column(){
        Text(text="Main Screen", fontSize=25.sp)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager,onSendColor: (Color)->Unit){
    var isExpanded by  remember{
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val color = remember{
        mutableStateOf(MyGray)
    }
    val colorText = remember{
        mutableStateOf("Gray")
    }
    val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(expanded = isExpanded,
            onExpandedChange = {isExpanded = it}) {
            TextField(value = colorText.value,
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                trailingIcon = {
                    ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = isExpanded)
                },
                colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
                modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenu(expanded = isExpanded, onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false }) {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = {
                        Text(text = "Gray")
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        colorText.value = "Gray"
                        color.value = MyGray
                        coroutine.launch {
                            dataStoreManager.saveColor(color.value.toString().toLong())
                        }
                        onSendColor(color.value)
                        isExpanded = false
                    })
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = {
                        Text(text = "Blue")
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        colorText.value = "Blue"
                        color.value = MyBlue
                        coroutine.launch {
                            dataStoreManager.saveColor(color.value.toString().toLong())
                        }
                        onSendColor(color.value)
                        isExpanded = false
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this colors, created in Color.kt:

```
val MyGray = Color(0xFF757575)
val MyBlue = Color(0xFF004285)
```

And it's my MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Home
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.material3.DrawerValue
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.ModalDrawerSheet
import androidx.compose.material3.ModalNavigationDrawer
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationDrawerItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberDrawerState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.drawercolorchange.ui.theme.DrawerColorChangeTheme
import com.example.drawercolorchange.ui.theme.MyGray
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val dataStoreManager = DataStoreManager(this)
        setContent {
            DrawerColorChangeTheme {
                val selectedColor = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(MyGray)
                }
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
                    dataStoreManager.getSettings().collect{
                        selectedColor.value = it as Color
                    }
                }
                Drawer(color = selectedColor, dataStoreManager)
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Drawer(color: MutableState<Color>, dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager){
    val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val menuList = listOf(Icons.Default.Home to "Home", Icons.Default.Settings to "Settings")
    var selectedItem by remember{mutableStateOf(-1)}
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState=drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet{
                menuList.forEachIndexed { index, data ->
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        icon={
                            Icon(imageVector = data.first, contentDescription = data.second)
                        },
                        label = {
                            Text(data.second)
                        },
                        selected=selectedItem==index,
                        onClick={
                            scope.launch{
                                selectedItem = index
                                drawerState.close()
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                MyTopAppBar(appBarColor = color.value){
                    scope.launch{
                        drawerState.open()
                    }
                }
            }
        ){
            Column(modifier=Modifier.padding(it)){
                when(selectedItem){
                    0 -> MainScreen()
                    1 -> SettingsScreen(onSendColor = {
                        color.value=it
                    })
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(appBarColor:Color, callback: () -> Unit){
    TopAppBar(
        colors=TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = appBarColor
        ),
        title = {
            Text("Main Screen", color=Color.White)
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = callback) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Menu, tint=Color.White, contentDescription = "Menu")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?